# How to create the Advanced Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a Advanced DataGrid requirement. But i do not have idea how to create it.
Please help me on this. I am attaching the Jpeg file.

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this table doesn't have dynamically added fields, I recommend the use of a form, a canvas or some nested boxes for displaying your data. Otherwise, you can do it like this:

- Create an ArrayCollection as dataprovider for the ADG
- Add an Object with the fields "construct", "today", "week", "month", "group" for each row of the table
- "group" stands for "Environment Size", "Availability", "Performance" and "Utilization"
- Add columns for the elements 1-4 in the ADG
- Group the ADG by the field "group"

Comment: it is not working.
pls check my code..

[Bindable]
  public var advGrid:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([
  
   {ioManagement:"hello", today:111, week:12, month:11, group:"env"},
   {ioManagement:"hello", today:111, week:12, month:11, group:"env"},
   {ioManagement:"hello", today:111, week:12, month:11, group:"env2"},
   {ioManagement:"hello", today:111, week:12, month:11, group:"env2"} ]);

Comment: <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adv" dataProvider="{advGrid}" width="100%" height="100%" columns="group">   
   <mx:groupedColumns>   
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="ioManagement" headerText="I/O Management Construct"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="today" headerText="Today"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="week" headerText="Week"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="month" headerText="Month"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="group" headerText="Group"/>
   </mx:groupedColumns>   
  </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

Comment: I know how to create a Advanced datagrid. But i tried like the attachment, i did not get idea, how to get it. Please check my above code and please help me where i did mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Flex Builder 3 **Professional Edition**? The AdvancedDataGrid is only available in the Professional edition of the tool.

From the Adobe website:

> Interactive data visualization
>   (Enhanced in Flex Builder 3)
>   (Professional edition only)
>
> Create data dashboards and interactive
>   data analysis by simply dragging and
>   dropping a chart type and linking it
>   to a data source using the Flex
>   charting library. Use the powerful new
>   Advanced Datagrid to enable users to
>   explore complex data.
>
> New in Flex Builder 3 — Use the
>   powerful new Advanced Datagrid to
>   enable users to explore complex data.
>   Charts have also been enhanced with
>   new interaction support, a drawing
>   API, and support for multiple axes.